# Complement of a SQL Join? T-SQL help needed

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

I will try to make my question sound as unconfusing as possible. I appologize in advance for any wording mistakes as I try to phrase my question as best as I can:

Using T-SQL I need to write a join statement that gets me all the results that have a match in table A and table B

AND (!)

another join statement (or a continuation of the first join) that returns all the results from table A that DID NOT have a match in table B, BUT in this second result set I need to have one of the columns set to "N/A" to identify the records that didn't have a match.

In other words, I need something that would return everything in table A but would also identify the rows that weren't matched in B. That information is then used in a report.

Here is what I have so far:

I have the first part done:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.chart B
ON B.UserName = A.user_name
```

That gets me the matching records and just the matching records

I tried adding this second join:

```
JOIN dbo.chart
ON NOT EXISTS (select * from B.UserName = A.user_name)
```

Hoping it would get me the non-matching records (I was planning to then use REPLACE on the column of interest to label that column "N/A") but there is something clearly wrong with my synthax as that generates exceptions.

My question is what do I need to change to get me the results you need. I do know that I need to have at least one join as I have other part of the query to work with. I just don't know if I need to have that one join return both sets of data of I actually do need a second one just for the non-matching records.

Hope this wasn't too confusing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

**Update: I would just like to emphasize that the reason I considered using a second join instead of getting all of the results at once is because I need to correctly identify and label those rows that weren't matched within everything that I get back.**

Comment: `left outer join` should give you what you want. All rows from A and joined to B where there is a match. Do you have a WHERE condition on some column in table B? If you do, that would make the outer join into a inner join and you need to move the check against columns in table B to the join clause.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Mikael. The biggest thing that I want to accomplish (and the main reason why I considered using a second join) is to be able to identify and lablel which rows where matched and which were not.

Comment: You don't need an extra join for that. Use `coalesce` as suggested by Mark in a comment to Dems answer.

Comment: I'll do that. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, I'm not entirely sure where `coalesce` should go. Which select clause was Mark referring to?

Comment: In the field list where you reference a column from table B. `coalesce(B.somecolumn, 'N/A') as SomeColumn`

Comment: For some reason, I am getting "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'coalesce'" when I try that. Any chance you could post the entire thing as I strongly suspect I'm messing something up? Thank you.

Comment: Added an answer with some options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample data:

```
declare @TableA table
(
  TableAID int,
  TableAName varchar(10)
)

declare @TableB table
(
  TableBID int,
  TableBName varchar(10),
  TableAID int
)

insert into @TableA values
(1, 'A 1'),
(2, 'A 2'),
(3, 'A 3')

insert into @TableB values
(1, 'B 1', 1),
(2, 'B 2', 2)
```

N/A instead of TableBName:

```
select A.TableAName,
       coalesce(B.TableBName, 'N/A') as TableBName
from @TableA as A
  left outer join @TableB as B
    on A.TableAID = B.TableAID
```

Result:

```
TableAName TableBName
---------- ----------
A 1        B 1
A 2        B 2
A 3        N/A
```

Extra column for N/A:

```
select A.TableAName,
       B.TableBName,
       case when B.TableBID is null 
         then 'N/A' 
         else '' 
       end as TableBPresent
from @TableA as A
  left outer join @TableB as B
    on A.TableAID = B.TableAID
```

Result:

```
TableAName TableBName TableBPresent
---------- ---------- -------------
A 1        B 1        
A 2        B 2        
A 3        NULL       N/A
```

Comment: Here is one correction to make it perfect:

`select A.TableAName, 
       coalesce(B.TableBName, 'N/A') as TableBName 
from @TableA as A 
  left outer join select TableID from B on A.TableAID = B.TableAID`

Comment: @user1179071 your query is invalid

Comment: It's working for me. Something might be different in how everything is combined.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure where you are going with the second join.  LEFT JOIN seems to do everything you want...

```
DECLARE @tableA TABLE (a_id INT) INSERT INTO @tableA VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4)
DECLARE @tableB TABLE (b_id INT) INSERT INTO @tableB VALUES      (2), (3)

SELECT * FROM @tableA AS A LEFT JOIN @tableB AS B on A.a_id = b.b_id

 a_id | b_id
------+------
   1  | NULL
   2  |  2
   3  |  3
   4  | NULL
```

Unless you mean that you're actually joining 3 tables together?

```
DECLARE @org    TABLE (o_io INT) INSERT INTO @org    VALUE       (2), (3), (4)
DECLARE @tableA TABLE (a_id INT) INSERT INTO @tableA VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4)
DECLARE @tableB TABLE (b_id INT) INSERT INTO @tableB VALUES      (2), (3)

SELECT
  *
FROM
  @org        AS O
INNER JOIN
  @tableA     AS A
    ON O.o_id = A.a_id
LEFT JOIN
  @tableB     AS B
    ON A.a_id = b.b_id

 o_id | a_id | b_id
------+------+------
   2  |   2  |  2
   3  |   3  |  3
   4  |   4  | NULL
```

Comment: +1 Add a `coalesce(B.UserName,'N/A')` (or other appropriate tableB column) to the select clause to fulfill the OP's requirement for "N/A"-labelled records with no matching tableB record.

Comment: Dems, thank you for your response. The are actually only two tables that I am working with (dbo.chart and dbo.orgchart are one and the same). I will correct my type in the question.

Comment: Mark, I will try out your suggestion in combination with what Dems wrote. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a union:

```
select A.id, b.id, b.desc from tablea A LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.chart B
ON B.UserName = A.user_name

UNION 

select a.id, 0, 'N/A' from tablea where NOT EXISTS (select * from B.UserName = A.user_name)
```

Comment: You need to fix your NOT EXISTS.  Select * from B where ...  And it should be an inner join.

Comment: Thank you. Trying out everything that was suggested.